# How to add column in table from a data of another table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to add a column to a table from data of another table. What I want is like

```
Select Mname, datatype from tableA
```

This query will return data like this:

```
A|float
B|float
C|int
```

I want to add this data as a column name with datatype of the data in another table

```
Alter table tableB 
Add A float null, B float null, C int null
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How do you know what data type you need? I doubt that all those columns are likely to contain 8,000+ characters and *up to* 2 billion.

Comment: Actually I gave an example for that but yes I also have to take the datatype from the same table where taking out the data. Thank you @Larnu

Comment: What happens if you have a data type like `varchar`, `decimal` or `datetime2`? Where are the precision and scale stored?

Comment: My tableA holds the record for the same with a column name datatype. If you can help me just with that sir I would be very much thankful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL for this. As, however, you have no column for the scale and precision, then the defaults will be used. For something like a `datetime2` this'll be `(7)`, but for a `decimal` this would be `(18,0)` and a `varchar` it would be `(1)`, which could make them unsuitable. As such you likely need to address you design to include the precision and scale.

I also check that the data type in `datatype` actually exists and that the column *doesn't* already exist in the table `TableB`; the columns will be omitted if they would cause problems. You can omit this logic if you want, which would mean that if the data type doesn't exist, an error would be thrown; it depends what behaviour you want.

I also *assume* you are using a fully supported version of SQL Server; if not, you'll need to use the "old" `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) method for your string aggregation.

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT @SQL = N'ALTER TABLE dbo.TableB ADD ' + STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(A.Mname) + N' ' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + N' NULL',N', ') + N';'
FROM dbo.TableA A
     JOIN sys.types t ON A.datatype = t.[name]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM sys.columns c
                  WHERE c.name = A.Mname
                    AND c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.TableA'));

--PRINT @SQL;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qbh56ZcR)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following **Dynamic SQL**

But the **`STRING_AGG()`** will working on **`SQL Server 2017`** and later versions only.

```
create table tableA (mname varchar(10), datatype varchar(100))
create table tableB (id int)

insert into tableA Values('A','int')
insert into tableA Values('B','float')
insert into tableA Values('C','int')

declare @ColNames varchar(1000) = '', @executeQuery NVARCHAR (MAX)

select @ColNames = STRING_AGG(mname + ' ' + datatype,',') from tableA

SELECT @executeQuery = 'Alter table tableB ADD ' + @ColNames

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @executeQuery;

select * from tableB

drop table tableA
drop table tableB
```

Comment: Careful, the syntax `SELECT @Variable = @Variable + ... FROM` is a [documented antipattern](//learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) and should be avoided; it relies on the data engine processing your in a row by row order, which there is *no* guarantee of.

Comment: I'm also not a fan of syntax like `EXEC (@SQL);`. Such statements cannot be parametrised, which promote bad habits that result in security flaws like SQL injection. If you need to run a statement that is within a variable or literal string then use [`sys.sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql). Then you can easily parametrise the statement if you need to.

Comment: @Larnu, thanks for the suggestions and warnings. I'll delete the answer now.

Comment: I'm not specifically saying it should be deleted, just that there are potential flaws.

Comment: @Larnu, Yes, I can understand your point. This may lead someone in the wrong way. I'm happy to take your advice. :)